# Google Adsense with sticky contents div

Tags: scrollbar, ads, adsense, sticky

One of my client needs to have ads in the left and right position besides content div. While content div has a scrollbar if the contents list is larger then the height of the div then it will have scrollbar. Now I just need to have a clarification on this as if it's supported in google adsense or not.

I'm aware of google ads inside sticky divs. But this is something different. Please let me know thanks!

**Screen shot for demonstration**

[image: Demo shot]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save your google adsense account you just follow the google adsense policies very strictly. Google is very strict about their policies.
So I would recommend not to use sidebar, as u mentioned those are not sticky but the look like sticky.
Here is a link follow this for better adsense income.

[A Blog - Home Page from google adsense](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/187651?guide=29872&ref_topic=29880)

Another layout u can take a reference from here..
[**Mobile Friendly Responsive Layout**](http://www.includehelp.com/blog/how-i-increased-organic-searches-on-my-website.aspx)

Comment: Here is things are different. My contents and ads are not stick. I'm using a fix height to the content div and then i m applying scrollbars to that div if the contents exceeded in length of that height, then i m showing scrollbars to the content div. If you resize the screen due to fix height windows scrollbar appears or disappears. Tell me if this type of layout is okey?

Comment: If you do this there may be accidental click chance on ad, if some one scrolls down the div click can be happened.. I hope u cna understand.

Comment: the above is just a design but not the actual screen shot. In bootstrap 3 columns there is enough margins between columns so no accidental click. and most of the users don't click on the scrollbar for dragging. Most of the users uses the mouse scrolling wheel or in mobile users uses touch swap

Comment: After reading adsense policies, you can go ahead.. if is there no accidental click happens..  u can implement.. best of luck